# Displaying data based on condition in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I am developing a report in SSRS and need help with displaying the data based on a few conditions.

**2 CONDITIONS:** (Please refer the image below)

1) 3 days in the Current Full Week with % above the 2% bench mark

It means that if a Restaurant R2 and R5 are not having  has minimum of 3 values > 2% so it should be eliminated

OR

2) 5 days in the Current Full Week & Prior Week (i.e. across the last 2 weeks) with % above the 2% bench mark

Here again R2 and R5 should be eliminated from report as Current Week and Prior Week values are not having minimum of 5 values  >2%

Report:

[image]

The report structure is:

[image]

**Final Output:**

[image]

So in short the report should only display restaurants meeting the above 2 conditions.

Comment: are you asking how to create your query or how to format the report?

Comment: I am asking how to write a query in report to meet the conditions stated.

Comment: Please see my edited question . It might give you a better understanding of the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Row Visibility to control it.
(As shown in your screenshot above) Left click the gray box on the left to the [StateName], select "Rowe Visibility", then "Show or hide based on an expression", and apply your condition there.

Comment: I want to know what condition can be used.